# Is it possible to extend Doctrine EntityGenerator?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm searching a way to add some named methods (like the setters/getters), on each generated property (based on the database).

By practical example, one of favorite "cheats" is an `$obj->{'init' . $name}($default_value)`.

Any idea, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a way, by writing my own Doctrine commands, using my own EntityGenerator subclass.

Example soon ;)

---

Edit : As promised, here is my custom generator : https://github.com/dom-arch/indoctrinated/blob/master/lib/Entity/Generator/Generator.php